# How to modify section 0 in Moodle 1.9?

Tags: php, moodle

I want to have resources at section 0, just like the http://moodlecommons.org site does. I found the code for section 0 at \course\format\topics\format.php but I don´t know where to modify the activity/resource type that appears in that section. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The code for this section seems to be located just a few lines under, in

```
echo '<div class="content">';
if (!is_null($thissection->name)) {
    echo $OUTPUT->heading(format_string($thissection->name, true, array('context' => $context)), 3, 'sectionname');
}

//CODE PERSONNALISE POUR CHAQUE DUT
echo '<div class="summary">';
echo '</div>';
```